# Crash when tap Home during update data and show dialogFragment. IllegalStateException

Tags: android, crash, illegalstateexception

In my case, in settings my app, I tap to button for update db and it show me dialogFragment with progress, and if I tap Home-button - my app crash.

Log errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1489)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1507)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:201)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:167)
                                                                        at com.guardian.glass.ui.settings.SettingsActivity$6.onComplete(SettingsActivity.java:328)
                                                                        at com.guardian.glass.ui.DialogProgressFragment$1.onDataLoaded(DialogProgressFragment.java:63)
```

In my class SettingsActivity code of method where pops up error.

```
private void fetchDatabaseFromServer() {
        UserOperationsTask getCountriesTask = new UpdateCountries(new DialogProgressFragment() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(boolean success) {
                dismiss(); // here i get error
                updateDatabaseSize();
                updateFilters();
                MeasureUtils.makeDefaultTemplate(SettingsActivity.this, true);
            }
        });
        getCountriesTask.execute(SettingsActivity.this);
        showProgress();
        updateDataBaseProfile();
    }
```

My inner class

```
private class UpdateCountries extends UserOperationsTask {
        final DialogProgressFragment progressDialog;

        UpdateCountries(DialogProgressFragment progressDialog) {
            super(UserOperationsTask.TaskMode.MODE_LOAD_COUNTRIES, null);
            this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Bundle resultData) {
            setRegionLabels();
            updateFilters();
            hideProgress();
            String errorMessage = resultData.getString(UserOperationsTask.RESULT_ERROR_STRING);
            if (errorMessage != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getCountriesFromServer error: " + errorMessage);
                showMessage(getString(R.string.info_title), getString(R.string.server_request_error));
            } else {
                progressDialog.start(SettingsActivity.this, DialogProgressFragment.DialogMode.MODE_UPDATE);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DialogProgressFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Tell me please how best to solve this problem?

Comment: try to put updating process in background service for notifying UI use broadcast receivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys! I finded solution - in my case, instead

```
dismiss();
```

better use

```
dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

Answer (score 0):

The caution, If you update ui after onstop the app will automatically get crash.
So if you are asynchronously updating ui of the app make sure their is some mechanism that detect your activity is not in onstop state.

Or you can change commit to commitAllowingStateLoss in dialogfragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Use commitAllowingStateLoss() instead of commit(). it doesn't throw an exception if state loss occurs.